# Error : "Forbidden" when doing GeocodeRequest in Here-API for android

Tags: android, kotlin, here-api

When doing a Geocoderequest in the Here API for Android I get the result "FORBIDDEN" for any search string.

Here is a snippet of the code ( Kotlin) :

```
class GeoListner : ResultListener <MutableList<Location>>
{
override fun onCompleted(p0: MutableList<Location>?, p1: ErrorCode?) {
   Log.d(this.javaClass.toString(),"Result code of search is ${p1?.name}")
}

}

    fab_search.setOnClickListener { View ->
        var currentPos = GeoCoordinate(49.2849,-123.1252)
        val listner : ResultListener<MutableList<Location>> = GeoListner()
        val request = GeocodeRequest("Granville").setSearchArea(currentPos,5000)
        if (request.execute(listner) != ErrorCode.NONE)
        {

        }
    }
```

This search area and string is picked from the API documentation for Here. Also i notice that the `GeocodeRequest` is deprecated, but the result for `GeocodeRequest2` is the same error.

Comment: Ok it turns out that Google Maps uses public IP

Comment: Sir,maybe you exceeded daily quota check the Docs for that

Comment: Don't think it's the daily quota since this is the first attempt to do use that api, it should be more than 1 request in the allowance.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but did you add your credentials (APP_ID and APP_CODE) to the manifest file, as described [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/dev_guide/topics/credentials.html)?

Comment: That is not a silly question at all. I have put APP_ID and APP_CODE in the manifest file as described, but at closer inspection I discovered that the cut-and-paste devil has omitted the first character in the value I pasted in to my manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: Please ensure that you set the APP_ID and APP_CODE in the manifest file correctly.

For the background:  Developers using HERE SDK with their app are required to register for a set of HERE credentials and to specify these credentials (App_Id and App_Code) in their app's Android manifest XML file. Failure to do so results in blocked access to certain features and degradation in the quality of other services.

To obtain these credentials visit the developer portal at https://developer.here.com/plans and register for a license. Once your project is created, you can generate these credentials on your Project Details page. If you already have a plan, you can also retrieve these credentials from your Project Details page.
Note: Credentials are unique to your account and your application's package namespace. Avoid reusing credentials across multiple applications.